# How to validation slug in laravel 5.4.24

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, slug

How to create unique slug in laravel and validate them ?

Here is my validation code:

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'company_name' => 'required|unique:admin_users,company_name,slug|max:191',
    ]);
```

Here is my slug code:

```
$db_filed->company_name = str_slug($request->company_name, '-');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying this way and now it's work,

Here is code form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" name="company_name" value="{{ ucwords(str_replace('-',' ',old('company_name'))) }}" required>
 </div>
```

Here is controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request['company_name'] = str_slug($request->company_name, '-');

    $this->validate($request,[
        'company_name' => "required|unique:admin_users,company_name|max:191",
    ]);
    $db_filed = new AdminUser;
    $db_filed->company_name = $request->company_name; 

    $db_filed->save();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom rule in to achieve this. Something like this should be enough:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Slug implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value): bool
    {
        $validSlug = (string) Str::of($value)->slug('-');

        return $value === $validSlug;
    }

    public function message(): string
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be slug formatted.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setup a FormRequest to do the validation for the route with the rules like this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
         'company_name' => 'required|unique:admin_users,company_name,slug|max:191'
    ];
}
```

Or you need to create the slug before assigning it to the company name.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators

```
$slug = str_slug($request->company_name, '-');

$validator = Validator::make(['company_name' => $slug], [
    'company_name' => 'required|unique:admin_users,company_name,slug|max:191'
]);

if (!$validator->fails()) {
    $db_filed->company_name = $slug;
    $db_filled->save();
}
```

Comment: Hi Btl,

Thanks for your valuable reply. I'm trying this two way but it's didn't work. But other field is work, as like email and phone those field are validate and  checked unique field. I can't understand why slug validation didn't work...

Comment: Can you give a example of real input data that does pass and an example of a company name that fails?

Comment: Here is form: https://prnt.sc/fkspf6
Here is controller: https://prnt.sc/fkspn6

I was try those two way then i'm undo those and this is my old code before trying.

Comment: use `$request->all()` when passing the request object into the validator.

Comment: hmm ok my mistake.. does it give any info on the input that fail?

Comment: validate others unique field and adding $request->all() then showing this error: prntscr.com/fksylj

Comment: Hi Buddy,

Thanks for your help, I'm solve this problem.
Here is solve form: https://prnt.sc/fku6d2
Here is controller: https://prnt.sc/fku6z2

Answer (score 0):

you can create the slug inside your controller probably inside the store function like this

```
public function store(CompanyNameRequest $request)
{
    $slug = uniqid();
    $ticket = new CompaanyName(array(
        'title' => $request->get('title'),
        'content' => $request->get('content'),
        'slug' => $slug
    ));

    $ticket->save();

    return redirect('/contact')->with('status', 'Your order is been proccess! Its unique id is: '.$slug);

}
```