# Laravel | Validate generated value

Tags: laravel, validation, request

I have an endpoint for data create.

The request is "name". I need to generate "slug" and validate that slug is unique.
So, let's say

book_genres table.

id | name | slug

Request is `["name" => "My first genre"]`.
I have a custom request with a rule:
"name" => "string|unique:book_genres,name".
I need the same check for the slug. 
`$slug = str_slug($name);`

How can I add this validation to my custom request?

Custom request class:

```
 class BookGenreCreate extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "name" => 'required|string|unique:book_genres,name',
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: make a new rule. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validation slug in laravel 5.4.24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601469/how-to-validation-slug-in-laravel-5-4-24)

Comment: Can you add the code of your custom request, please?

Comment: @Jonathon sure. One sec

Comment: @Jonathon it's form request class. It's quite basic. I need to inject generated slug to validated data somehow. It's my question. I don't want to validate in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically what you want to do is try to manipulate the request data before validation occurs. You can do this in your `FormRequest` class by overriding one of the methods that is called before validation occurs. I've found that this works best by overriding `getValidatorInstance`. You can then grab the existing data, add your slug to it and then replace the data within the request, all before validation occurs:

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $data = $this->all();
    $data['slug'] = str_slug($data['name']);
    $this->getInputSource()->replace($data);

    return parent::getValidatorInstance();
}
```

You can also add the rules for your slug to your rules method as well:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "name" => 'required|string|unique:book_genres,name',
        "slug" => 'required|string|unique:book_genres,slug',
    ];
}
```

So your class will look something like this:

```
class BookGenreCreate extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|unique:book_genres,name',
            'slug' => 'required|string|unique:book_genres,slug',
        ];
    }

    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $data = $this->all();
        $data['slug'] = str_slug($data['name']);
        $this->getInputSource()->replace($data);

        return parent::getValidatorInstance();
    }
}
```

Now when the request comes through to your controller, it will have been validated and you can access the slug from the request object:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function store(BookGenreCreate $request)
    {
        $slug = $request->input('slug');

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 'slug' to the request, then use validations as usual.

```
rules() {

    // set new property 'slug' to the request object.
    $this->request->set('slug', str_slug($request->name));

    // rules
    return [
        'name' => 'string|unique:book_genres,name',
        'slug' => 'string|unique:book_genres,slug'
    ]
}
```